# How to make a small space between the input fields?

Tags: html, css, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

How to make a small space between the input fields? Only without using the table as shown in the example of Angular Material.

```
<div class="content pt10" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxFlexFill>
    <div fxFlex="50">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Test1">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="50">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput type="text" placeholder=" Test2">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that you have used `pt10` that will give you 10px padding on top so based on that logic i would suggest you to add `mb10` which will leave the 10px margin space at the bottom to your first input.

```
<div class="content pt10" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxFlexFill>
<div class="mb10"fxFlex="50">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Test1">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div fxFlex="50">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput type="text" placeholder=" Test2">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Me helped `mr10`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="content pt10" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="10px">
        <div fxFlex>
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Test1">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex>
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput type="text" placeholder=" Test2">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
```

you will use fxLayoutGap. if you want to increase the gap will increase fxLayoutGap=20px or 30px

Answer (score 0):

you can simply just use

```
<br>
```

example:

```
<div class="content pt10" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxFlexFill>
    <div fxFlex="50">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Test1">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div fxFlex="50">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput type="text" placeholder=" Test2">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
```

or use css to increase the margin of blocks.
see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp